# How to sort TimeOfDay list from earliest to latest time?

Tags: flutter, timeofday

I need to display a schedule for users that displays times from earliest to latest time. I have a TimeOfDay list containing times and need it to be sorted from earliest to latest time. I made a function for it, but keep getting _TypeError (type 'TimeOfDay' is not a subtype of type 'String') when I run my code. Since I utilize the function inside a Column in my Widget build code block, I think it has to return a widget. Please let me know how I can resolve this error and efficiently sort my list through a function. The code for my function is below, any help would be appreciated!

```
  listOrder(l) {
    l.sort((a,b) => DateTime.parse(a).compareTo(DateTime.parse(b)));
    return Text('Done!');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.parse` expects a `String` input, not a `TimeOfDay` instance.

If you want to sort a `List<TimeOfDay>`, you need to provide a comparison function that compares `TimeOfDay` instances:

```dart
int compareTimeOfDay(TimeOfDay time1, TimeOfDay time2) {
  var totalMinutes1 = time1.hour * 60 + time1.minute;
  var totalMinutes2 = time2.hour * 60 + time2.minute;
  return totalMinutes1.compareTo(totalMinutes2);
}

void main() {
  var list = [
    TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 59),
    TimeOfDay(hour: 2, minute: 3),
    TimeOfDay(hour: 22, minute: 10),
    TimeOfDay(hour: 9, minute: 30),
  ];

  list.sort(compareTimeOfDay);
  print(list);
}
```

Comment: How does list.sort(compareTimeOfDay); work? Because compareTimeOfDay takes in two arguments

Comment: @nsa41620 The callback to [`List.sort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/sort.html) is supposed to take exactly two arguments.  You yourself passed a callback that takes two arguments in the code that you tried.

Comment: My list has more than two arguments so how would I pass all of them through?

Comment: @nsa41620 Do you mean more than two *elements*?  The `List` in the example I've shown has more than two elements too.  A sorting algorithm compares two elements at a time.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are missing return value form sort method. since you are using curly brackets,

here i try on dartpad is working fine

```
void main() {
List date = ['2022-02-02','2022-02-15','2022-02-01'];
  
  date.sort((a,b) => DateTime.parse(a).compareTo(DateTime.parse(b)));
  
  print(date); //result : [2022-02-01, 2022-02-02, 2022-02-15]
}
```

if you have 1 argument, you can simplify with arrow `=>` , but if you have more than 1, use brackets `{}`

```
 l.sort((a,b){
     return  DateTime.parse(a).compareTo(DateTime.parse(b)); // see i add a return syntax
    });
```

Comment: I just edited my question with the new error. I need to use the function in a column in my widget build code block. Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide your list?  and what is TimeOfday object?

Comment: because, DateTime.parse required a string, not object

Comment: My list has times like 2:00 PM so how will these times be sorted from earliest to latest as Strings?